# Send binary of file from ajax to ashx file as application/octet-stream

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, ashx

I need to send with ajax a file Binary to .ashx file (c# .net environment).
When I send it, the "Request Payload" must be of Content-Type: "application/octet-stream", this is the requirement from the server side. My problem is When I run my script, It sends the file as a normal type instead of "application/octet-stream". if the file is jpg, then it sends it as Content-type: "image/jpeg", This is not good for me. I wanna send the file in Binary format.

right now what I have is this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',file);

$.ajax({
  url: gatewayUrl,
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(data){},
  error: function(){}
});
```

I read about FileReader, and about File.getAsBinary() but non of them is working for me. I am struggling with the ArrayBuffer and I'm not sure if I'm on the right direction..

This is the direction I'm thinking about but I can't figure out if that's the correct way to go with or not:

```
function get_file_binary(file){
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  fileReader.onload = function(e){
    var res = fileReader.result;
    var res2 = new Int8Array(res);
    return res2;
  }
}
```

But when I try this I get "undefined" at the "Request Payload" on chrome.